# Changing dropdownlist selection causes full postback. (it's more interesting than it sounds)

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

Here's the scenario.

I have a search page with a TextBox that allows someone to type in a search term and press enter. (Which fires TextChanged).  I have a DropDownList that specifies the kind of search that will be performed.  It is defined in the markup as follows:

```
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="lstSearchType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Last, First</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Last</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">First</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Liberty ID</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">E-mail</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Telephone</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="6">Birthday (exact m/d/yyyy)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="7">SSN (exact ###-##-####)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="8">Address</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

As you can see, AutoPostBack is set to false, and there is no event hookup.

Pressing enter fires the OnTextChanged event for the TextBox, which performs a search and updates a GridView in an UpdatePanel.  This UpdatePanel has its UpdateMode set to conditional and has one trigger: the TextChanged event of the search TextBox.

It's very simple.

And it works beautifully, almost.

Whenever I change the search type, the very next search does a full postback. All subsequent searches do partial postbacks (as desired) unless I change the search type again.

There is one exception to this rule: if I load the page and immediately change the search type, it doesn't do a full postback.  So the first change of the DropDownList before any postback (full or partial) does not trigger a full postback.

Full Disclosure:
I'm doing a lot of JavaScript to change the appearance of the gridview during async requests.  I don't detail it here because it seems unrelated. This problem only occurs when a DropDownList with no JavaScript wired up is changed.

Any ideas?

This is driving me crazy. Everything else is working.

Thanks in advance,
Clif

Comment: @clifriffin maybe you set dropdownlist to autopostback on the code of your program and you did not have notice that. In any case it is better to view the source code of the page and see if there is any javascript on this drop down list.

Comment: I figured it out. 

The problem was that the DropDownList was not in an UpdatePanel.  It had no way to get the value without doing a full postback.  The TextBox was immune to this because of the TextChanged event wiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that the DropDownList was not in an UpdatePanel. It had no way to get the value without doing a full postback. The TextBox was immune to this because of the TextChanged event wiring.